# Making a generic parameter optional based on another generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic like this:

```
type HTTPMethod = "HEAD" | "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | "PATCH" | "DELETE";
type Endpoint<M extends HTTPMethod, S extends {}> = () => void;
```

The "idea" is to supply a shape `S` when declaring an `Endpoint` function. `S` can be used as the input/output type.

However, I want `S` to be required for POST, PUT, PATCH, but **optional** for HEAD, GET, DELETE. Something like this:

```
const a: Endpoint = () => {}; // < requires 1 type argument(s).
const b: Endpoint<"HEAD"> = () => {};
const c: Endpoint<"HEAD", {}> = () => {};
const d: Endpoint<"POST"> = () => {}; // < requires 2 type argument(s).
const e: Endpoint<"POST", {}> = () => {};
```

It seems as though using `extends` and `=` doesn't work as I would've expected. This:

```
type Test<T extends string = number> = () => void;
```

Errors, because number does not satisfy string. However:

```
type Endpoint<M extends HTTPMethod, S extends M extends "POST" | "PUT" | "PATCH" 
  ? S extends unknown 
  ? never
  : {} 
  : never = unknown> = () => void;
```

–is always valid, despite the fact that `unknown` is not `never` nor `{}`. I've played around with the above for a couple hours, but I can't seem to find something that works.

Is such a thing possible with current TypeScript?

Comment: This is either impossible or not intended to be possible; type arguments are either required (because there is no default) or they are not (because there is a default); there's no support for "conditionally required type arguments".  It's possible that one might come up with a weird workaround, but if so, it's not something that TS is setting out to support.  What about a tuple type instead like `Endpoint<["HEAD"]>` vs `Endpoint<["POST", {}]>`? That would at least be possible.  How do you want to proceed here?

Comment: Like [this approach using tuples](https://tsplay.dev/w1n8kN) requires an extra `[` and `]` but otherwise behaves exactly as you want. Are you interested in seeing an answer written up that explains this approach?  Or would you rather see a properly-sourced "no this is impossible" answer?

Comment: I'm happy with your answer! Like you said, that lands me close enough to where I wanted, and also explains my misunderstanding.

Comment: If you're interested in what I'd consider the weird workaround, it could look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKPkKw).  *Maybe* that works for you? But it's weird.  What would you rather see here?

Comment: That's tough. Option 2 ends up being a bit cleaner, but option 1 is way easier to conceptualize. I'm going to try out your second link, but both are very good. I would throw both in, in that order, honestly.

Comment: Okay I'll describe both in my answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters in TypeScript can have [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), but if you use them the type argument is optional, and if you don't then the type argument is required.  There's no "conditionally optional" type parameters in TypeScript.  That means while it might be possible to get similar behavior to what you want, there's no feature that is *intended* to provide it.

---

One reasonable workaround is to use a single [tuple-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) type parameter instead of a variadic number of type parameters.  So instead of `Endpoint<X, Y>` you would write `Endpoint<[X, Y]>`.  There's a lot more support for tuples of varying length and whose length depends on some condition than there is for generic type parameters.

Here's one way to do that:

```
type NeedExtra = "POST" | "PUT" | "PATCH";

type Allowed = HTTPMethod extends infer H ? H extends NeedExtra ?
    [H, any] : [H, any?] : never;

// type Allowed = ["HEAD", any?] | ["GET", any?] | ["POST", any] | 
//  ["PUT", any] | ["PATCH", any] | ["DELETE", any?]
```

So `Allowed` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of tuple types of two elements, where the second element is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) depending on the first element type.

Then you can define `Endpoint` as having its type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Allowed`:

```
type Endpoint<M extends Allowed> = () => void;
const a: Endpoint<[]> = () => { }; // error
// -------------> ~~
// Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 1
const b: Endpoint<["HEAD"]> = () => { };
const c: Endpoint<["HEAD", {}]> = () => { };
const d: Endpoint<["POST"]> = () => { }; // error
// -------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
const e: Endpoint<["POST", {}]> = () => { };
```

That works how you want.  The downside is that it requires a tuple wrapper, but the upside is that it's fairly straightforward.  You can just look at `Allowed` and read off what you should and shouldn't be able to do.

---

Another workaround is to make the desired error appear on the *first* type argument instead of the "missing" second argument.  That is, we can't make the second argument "conditionally optional", but we can constrain the first type parameter so that an undesirable value for the second type argument makes the first type argument fail to meet its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

It could look like this:

```
type Endpoint<T extends (
    [T, U] extends [NeedExtra, never] ?
    Exclude<HTTPMethod, NeedExtra> :
    HTTPMethod
), U = never> = () => void
```

So the first type parameter `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to something that depends on itself and the second type parameter `U`.  (This happens not to trip the circularity alarms; if it did, we could have moved it to a third type parameter... but I digress).   I will assume that if the second type argument `U` is `never`, then it's the same as being missing (if you need to distinguish `never` from `missing` then we could create some "sigil" type, but that's even weirder).

So the constraint for `T` is either `HTTPMethod` or `Exclude<HTTPMethod, NeedExtra>` (everything that isn't `NeedExtra`), depending on `T` and `U`.  If `T` is assignable to `NeedExtra` but `U` is `never`, then there's a problem and we constrain `T` to everything that *isn't* `NeedExtra`, which will fail.  Otherwise then there's no problem and we constrain `T` to `HTTPMethod`.

Let's try it:

```
const a: Endpoint = () => { };
// ----> ~~~~~~~~
// error, Generic type 'Endpoint' requires between 1 and 3 type arguments.
const b: Endpoint<"HEAD"> = () => { };
const c: Endpoint<"HEAD", {}> = () => { };
const d: Endpoint<"POST"> = () => { }; // error, 
// -------------> ~~~~~~
// Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint '"HEAD" | "GET" | "DELETE"'.
const e: Endpoint<"POST", {}> = () => { };
```

Also looks good.  The errors are reasonable, and has the advantage of being very close to what you wanted.  The downside is that the constraint is more cryptic, and is definitely not *intended* to be supported by the language.  I could imagine a change to a future TypeScript version that would break this and require a refactoring (especially for circularity).  But for now it works and isn't horrendous.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgKnACgWQsAFgewCZQLxQBEMAogIIAihUAPkQOIlzV2GIDyAys7UYgKo9WiMnADCMFkQokAMkxKEA3AFgAUOtCQoAOQgRsJAB7AATgEN8fLkL6CpbURMLr1AO3MBbCAGcw5gGNoOABXMAAbCAB1TFMAa3NTTBC3XABvVzUobKgtaDJw8MwAdwMreCRUDBwoCBMIVJ8oAEs3ADMIU1goAH5uuuAG7Ca9A2MzSx71HJmoAG0YABooczcQAF0oAC55pZW1ns2dtwgAN07VDSycgHob3PB8wpKygjnicipl1ZBD3nfGMxvgdNnR3hxuIRgRteNNbvd5mx7NDQYiROJJCj-oQZPI4IpoYdMjM8lASKkwJhWsAADzIWr1RpQApFUrYAB8VgAFABKfCc05U7CXGYBTBuHzAFY7cnYSnUmlzdacgi8-lQNJQAC+Sigd1qpiSpjh2X1AFoLZarZbOQA-W0mvX3TjJUxBKDocxNAAMtUi3jcwC5Pj5ACMQlLgIkAOZoKCmCAARxCzQTTQAjI6xRKpaGZRSqYHFR9KIRldy+XhOZqdVnxZKoAF83LC7T3qRS8s0lry6rK9XtSKctmG9hm-Ki+CbGWVVA1VWNYOnQajY7zdaN2a7fad-a1-c4I8VlLKT5msBmuKoL7WlAfK73c0mm5MFKxZ5-BfQ5EoMVz+gHm0cwT0wM8LyvG83FyGM0AAOjrHNanHVtiwhIENR7Wd5wHWs1C1TIPG8PxAmgGJ4kSZJUgAJg1YkclJWUJ1pOAGUGJkuUdGY5jgZZ+E2AYhiaOZRkMEwLGWE5zlMTYpmuWYySMAJwhCbAIBpCoUDQLBsGWETxgsTktk4nINKqbTHR5XirEkzosP7KBBWabBMgQhtzGQ6kK3VGsh1Ne4rW3Xc9zk5dOiNZZ6AaTpmgCQDoAAckY1t4vjJMUzTKBQzQUoGigdN9lwABmOKVlMaMQgDYAfHgkKR1zDyixLKg7O8wdXLfBraSaqEMJahcfPaqAxzJAsFTYac+pw3V9TC2Jln3KBNw3QKdwWw9tHiyVTFaaMUuwTBfCgF8pR8YCnzaEBcnQaA6osTz4u63hCEBBxcQUQh4pq0V6ylCBOppcbIS7LVJsXXCXKuLUgA)